# Why my foreGround service stop if i press button "Clear all"

Tags: java, android, foreground-service

my permission in manifest

> uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"

service is

> android:stopWithTask="false"

onStartCommand returning the START_STICKY
and create the notification this code

> private void startForegroundService()
> {
>
> ```
>     Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
>     PendingIntent pendingIntent =
>             PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
>
>     Notification notification = null;
>     if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
>         notification = new Notification.Builder(this, "SEX")
>                         .setContentTitle("getText(R.string.notification_title)")
>                         .setContentText("getText(R.string.notification_message)")
>                         .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
>                         .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
>                         .setTicker("ssss")
>                         .build();
>     }else {
>         notification = new Notification.Builder(this)
>                 .setContentTitle("getText(R.string.notification_title)")
>                 .setContentText("getText(R.string.notification_message)")
>                 .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
>                 .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
>                 .setTicker("ssss")
>                 .build();
>     }
>     startForeground(423, notification);
>
> }
> ```

But if i push button "Clear all" my service is dead without call onTaskRemoved

Answer (score 0):

What you need is an [ongoing notification](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder#setOngoing(boolean)), set it on your `Notification.Builder` object:

```
notification = ...
        ...
        .setOngoing(true)
        .build();
```